# Replacement for Java Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn, graalvm

I'm not asking what the alternatives are. But, what's the "official" line on what to do about Java Nashorn deprecation now (December 2019). Are you supposed to just wait. Is graalvm to become part of the JDK or are the parts of it that are needed for Javascript support going to be part of the JDK or what? Am I going to need to pay for graalvm enterprise (just to have Javascript like I had before through Nashorn in a closed source application) is that where Oracle is taking this?

Comment: This sounds like a question better suited to a mailing list.

Comment: It sounds like it but it isn't.

Comment: Why would you have to pay for GraalVM EE to have JS in a closed source application? GraalVM CE is a thing...

Comment: Yes, it's under GPL with classpath exception but you currently can't just get the needed jar files from the distribution. Some of it is packaged in modules now with which I suppose you can generate a 'custom' jre with jlink. Is that covered by classpath exception? Also there seems to be a lot of bits and pieces with their own license that are used by graal.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript library which is compatible `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265629 for one answer