# How to add the Nashorn module to Tomcat 10

Tags: java, tomcat, nashorn

I want to add the Nashorn module to my Tomcat 10, but I haven't found a way how to do that. I am using OpenJDK 19. I downloaded the Nashorn jar file from here: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core/15.4/jar. I added it to the lib directory of my Tomcat server, but it didn't work.

So maybe someone of you can help me how one can add the Nashorn module to Tomcat 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Nashorn in Java 15 and later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265629/how-to-use-nashorn-in-java-15-and-later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ASM 7.3.1 jars as well that Nashorn depends on, at least `asm-7.3.1.jar`, `asm-commons-7.3.1.jar`, `asm-tree-7.3.1.jar`, and `asm-util-7.3.1.jar`, you can also fetch them from Maven Central.