# Null pointer exception while trying to access js file using Java Nashorn

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nashorn

I'm trying to make an IDE for HolyC using Java. I already have worked on a simple text editor using Java so I used it as a base.

Apparently the interpreter that I'm planning to use for this IDE is written in JavaScript so I've tried loading the `.js` file by placing it in the same `src` folder as my `.java.` code.

I used Nashorn for this since I found it to be the most suitable engine for my project but the issue is that the code throws a null pointer exception when I run the code.

This is the error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=60192:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\aryan\OneDrive\Documents\Github\prometheus-ide\Prometheus IDE\out\production\Prometheus IDE" interpreter
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(java.io.Reader)" because "ee" is null
    at interpreter.main(interpreter.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and this is my code

```java
//importing modules
import javax.script.*;
import java.io.*;
public class interpreter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //calling nashorn js engine
        ScriptEngine ee = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Nashorn");
        ee.eval(new FileReader("C:/Users/aryan/OneDrive/Documents/Github/prometheus-ide/src/holyc-interpreter.js"));
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong because this is my first null pointer exception in Java

Comment: Nashorn was removed after JDK 14: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265629/how-to-use-nashorn-in-java-15-and-later

Comment: Any other alternatives?

Comment: Perhaps Rhino might do it?

Comment: Add it as a maven dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn

Comment: I'm gonna consider a different approach to my project since Nashorn is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nashorn has been deprecated in JDK 15 so it no longer exists in the JDK and throws a null pointer exception as told by @duffymo.

Rhino is an alternative suggested by @g00se